# Js Not adding Numbers correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I am trying to make some JS that will take an existing array and add a number to it using a variable. The problem, it's not returning an expected value. at `element[0][1] += rows` the console returns a value that it should not. For example, if `rows = 0;` and the `element[0][1] = 1;` console returns: **2**. I think it has something to do with my nested array as when i run a simple code such as:

```
let x = 1;
let g = [1,2,3];
g[0] += x;
console.log(g[0]);
```

All works well and the expected responce is reseaved, but am not sure.
Any help would be much appreciated and i simplified my code to help!

edit 2:
`numberOfObjects` is an integer and represents the number of elements that need an x and y position

```
var slides = [
    [
        [ [1,1],[3,1] ] //element 0 (start[x,y], end[x,y])
    ], // slide 0;
    
    [
        [ [1,1],[2,1] ], // element 0
        [ [3,1],[3,1] ]  //element 1 
    ], //slide 1

    [
        [ [1,1],[2,1] ], // element 0
        [ [3,1],[3,2] ], // element 1
        [ [1,2],[2,2] ]  // element 2
    ], //slide 2
    
    [
        [ [1,1],[1,1] ], // element 0
        [ [1,2],[1,3] ], // element 1
        [ [1,2],[2,3] ], // element 2
        [ [3,2],[3,3] ]  // element 3
    ], //slide 3
    
    [
        [ [1,1],[1,2] ], // element 0
        [ [2,1],[2,2] ], // element 1
        [ [3,1],[3,2] ], // element 2
        [ [1,3],[1,3] ], // element 3
        [ [2,3],[3,3] ]  // element 4
    ], //slide 4
    
    [
        [ [1,1],[1,1] ], // element 0
        [ [2,1],[2,1] ], // element 1
        [ [3,1],[3,2] ], // element 2
        [ [1,2],[2,2] ], // element 3
        [ [1,3],[1,3] ], // element 4
        [ [2,3],[3,3] ]  // element 5
    ]  //slide 5
]

function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  }

function collectSlides(numberOfObjects){

    
    //const N = numberOfObjects;
    var rows = 0;

    console.log("At row:"+rows);
    while (numberOfObjects > 0){
        if (numberOfObjects < 7){
            console.log("finished");
            numberOfObjects == 0;
        }
        else{
            let x = getRandomInt(6);
            let slide = slides[x];

            slide.forEach(element => {
                //console.log("org:"+element[0][1]);
                element[0][1] = rows;
                //console.log("aft:"+element[0][1]);
            });
            rows += (slide[slide.length-1][1][1] - rows);
            console.log(slide);
            numberOfObjects -= x;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit Some more info:

Functions are called with console for simplification but are nomaly called with an on page load event.

results expected, an array returnd from the function giveing me a generated list of element (listed thing above that resembles 2 tuples) with an updated y coordinates.

why? I plan to use css-grid to make a page where each element will span a selected row and columns given by the js.
[here is an image of what each slide will do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtJPt.png)
the goal of the `collectSlides()` function is to randomly pick from one of the slides and and add it to the retun array with the proper y coordinates.

edit 2: commented out `const N` because it is not relevent

edit 3: For repeating results i am using `Math.seedrandom("3232");` from [this code](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom) i first insert `seedrandom.min.js` with a script tag in html. I call the function in console with `collectSlides(22)` and when the output's first response is `(5) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]` under witch on `element[0]` you will find `0: (2) [1, 1] 1: (2) [1, 2]`. given the code 0: (2) [1, **1**] (the bolded number) should be a **0 not 1**.

Comment: How are the functions called? What result do you expect? Why? Please [edit] your post to fill in the details.

Comment: _“Functions are called with console for simplification but are nomaly called with an on page load event.”_ — How specifically? What arguments are you providing?

Comment: _“an array returnd from the function giveing me a generated list of element (listed thing above that resembles 2 tuples) with an updated y coordinates”_ — Which values precisely should the output array hold? How will we know if we’re on the right track? How can we compare the right result? The “why” question related to your expectations. Why do you expect what you expect?

Comment: _The “why” question related to your expectations. Why do you expect what you expect?_ - the `rows` var never seams to be applyed to the slide var

Answer (score 0):

The problem was trying to change numbers in an array that was aleardy made. I dont know why it did not work but I recoded it to avoid editing an existing array's numbers and it works now.

```
const SEED = "3232";
const USESEED = true;

var slides = [
    [
        [ [1,1],[3,1] ] //element 0 (start[x,y], end[x,y])
    ], // slide 0;
    
    [
        [ [1,1],[2,1] ], // element 0
        [ [3,1],[3,1] ]  //element 1 
    ], //slide 1

    [
        [ [1,1],[2,1] ], // element 0
        [ [3,1],[3,2] ], // element 1
        [ [1,2],[2,2] ]  // element 2
    ], //slide 2
    
    [
        [ [1,1],[1,1] ], // element 0
        [ [1,2],[1,3] ], // element 1
        [ [1,2],[2,3] ], // element 2
        [ [3,2],[3,3] ]  // element 3
    ], //slide 3
    
    [
        [ [1,1],[1,2] ], // element 0
        [ [2,1],[2,2] ], // element 1
        [ [3,1],[3,2] ], // element 2
        [ [1,3],[1,3] ], // element 3
        [ [2,3],[3,3] ]  // element 4
    ], //slide 4
    
    [
        [ [1,1],[1,1] ], // element 0
        [ [2,1],[2,1] ], // element 1
        [ [3,1],[3,2] ], // element 2
        [ [1,2],[2,2] ], // element 3
        [ [1,3],[1,3] ], // element 4
        [ [2,3],[3,3] ]  // element 5
    ]  //slide 5
]

function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  }

function collectSlides(numberOfObjects){

    if (USESEED){
        try{
            Math.seedrandom(SEED);
        }
        catch{
            alert(" this script requires seeded math.random functions from [https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom] in order to create a replicable pattern. to disable this warning set USESEED = False");
        }
    } 

    var rows = 0;
    elements = [];
    while (numberOfObjects > 0){
        
        if (numberOfObjects < slides.length+1){
            slides[numberOfObjects].forEach(element => {
                let slide = [];
                let q1 = [element[0][0],(element[0][1]+rows)];
                let q2 = [element[1][0],(element[1][1]+rows)];
                slide.push(q1,q2);
                elements.push(slide);
            });
            rows = elements[elements.length-1][1][1]
            numberOfObjects -= numberOfObjects;
        }
        else{
            let x = getRandomInt(6);

            slides[x].forEach(element => {
                let slide = [];
                let q1 = [element[0][0],(element[0][1]+rows)];
                let q2 = [element[1][0],(element[1][1]+rows)];
                slide.push(q1,q2);
                console.log(slide)
                elements.push(slide);
            });
            rows = elements[elements.length-1][1][1]
            numberOfObjects -= x;
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```